# I want to subtract field (A) - coin_charge value from field (B) coin value and store the result in field (B) coin

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

FIRST, I GOT TWO FIELD IN MySQL DATABASE field, COIN and field COIN_CHARGE here is the screen shot
[POPUP Screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqQqP.png),
i want the system to check if a user click YES, that is attempting to summit and proceed, let the system check through his database
[Database screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVc2R.png) and start this Argument, (if field -coin- is less than field -coin_charge-) is should popup a window saying, Insufficient Fund to proceed Top Up your account else, if the coin field is greater than the coin_charge field let the system subtract coin_charge from coin, which is, if (coin = 100) and (coin_charge =50) coin will become 50

----------------- POP UP MESSAGE ------------------------------

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Report Assignment</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Report Assignment Now!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>You Will Be Charge From Your Portal Account, Do You Wish To Continuo?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onClick="$('#createFormId').modal('show')" >YES</a>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">NO</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

---------------------------COMPUTING CODE---------------------------

```
<?php
    $message_query = mysql_query("select * from student ")or die(mysql_error());
?>

<?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        echo $row['coin'] = $row['coin'] - $row['coin_charge'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Thanks Jay Blanchard

Comment: INSERT INTO PRODUCT (name, price) VALUES (?, ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");
$userid = $_POST["userid"];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $userid);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$stmt->close();

$total = $row['coin'] - $row['coin_charge'];
if($total > 0){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("update student set coin = ? where id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $total, $userid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    echo $total;
}else{
    echo 'Insufficient Fund to proceed Top Up your account';exit;
}
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: mr P-gandhi, i used mysql can i still apply PDO code and mix them? thanks once again.

Comment: i used mysqli not pdo. you can use this way or you can simply take my logic and used it with your way. logic is same only way of coding is different. i hope you find your way. :)

Comment: <?php $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "capstone");


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = ?');

$stmt->bind_param('i', $total);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$stmt->close();
$total = $row['coin'] - $row['coin_charge'];
if($total > 0){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("update student set coin = ? where id = ?");
 
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $total);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
 
   echo $total;
 
}else{
    echo 'Insufficient Fund to proceed Top Up your account';exit;
}
?>

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\lms\moneycalculator.php on line 6

Comment: please i need help

Comment: hey mr pi-gandhi what is the use of this code in line 2 please $userid = $_POST["userid"];

Comment: you got fatal error bcos you didnt pass one parameter. please check my code. $stmt->bind_param("ii", $total, $userid);

Comment: Yes. i added $userid = $_POST["userid"]; . because as per your above description, i understood that you need to check this for one particular user. who are doing this process. this id is refer to that user himself. i hope you got my point